Explain the use of Mayer-Vietoris in the computation of the singular homology of $S^1$
I was reading the typed up notes of my algebraic topology course and could make neither head nor tail of one paragraph in them. First we let $f:[0,1]\rightarrow S^1$ be $f(t) = e^{2i\pi t}$. Now apply Mayer-Vietoris to $U=f([0, 0.5), (0.5,1])$ and $V=f((0,1))$.
Since $H_0(U) \cong H_0(V) \cong \mathbb{Z}$ and $H_0(U\cap V) \cong \mathbb{Z}^2$, we have the Mayer-Vietoris sequence:
\begin{equation}
    0 \rightarrow H_1(S^1) \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}^2 \rightarrow H_0(S^1)\rightarrow 0
\end{equation}
Let the map $\mathbb{Z}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}^2$ be $A$. I understand everything so far, but have no clue what is going on in the following paragraph.

To complete the computation we need to understand the map $A$. This map records how the inclusion induced maps send the connected components of $U \cap V$ to connected components of $U$ and $V$.
Since $U$ and $V$ are both connected, the map $\iota_U:H_0(U \cap V) \cong \mathbb{Z}^2 \rightarrow H_0(U) \cong \mathbb{Z}$ and $\iota_V$ defined similarly are both the map $\mathbb{Z}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}:(a,b) \rightarrow a+b$.

Given this paragraph, I understand the rest of the calculation, but no part of the above paragraph is clear to me. Thank you!

This comes down to understanding how induced maps on $H_0({{-}})$ work in general and how induced maps in general behave with respect to disjoint unions.
Recall that, given any path-connected space $X$, the group $H_0(X)$ is generated by the class of any point $x \in X$, viewed as a 0-cycle $* = \Delta^0 \to X$. In particular, if $f\colon X \to Y$ is a map between path-connected spaces, then $f_*\colon \mathbb{Z} \cong H_0(X) \to H_0(Y) \cong \mathbb{Z}$ can be canonically identified with $\mathrm{id}_{\mathbb{Z}}$: It takes a generator $[x]$ to the generator $[f(x)]$ (which is just a fancy way to say that a function maps points to points).
Now what if $X$ has two path components $X_1, X_2$? In this case, you can write it as $X = X_1 \sqcup X_2$, so you really have two maps $f_i\colon X_i \to Y$ with $f = f_1 \sqcup f_2\colon X = X_1 \sqcup X_2 \to Y$. Each of the $(f_i)_*$ identifies again with $\mathrm{id}_{\mathbb{Z}}$, so all that's left is to make sense of what happens in homology if you take a disjoint union, and for this you simply note generally that
$$
    f_*((a, b)) = f_*((a, 0) + (0, b)) = f_*((a, 0)) + f_*((0, b)) = (f_1)_*(a) + (f_2)_*(b)
$$
for all $(a, b) \in H_n(X_1) \oplus H_n(X_2) \cong H_n(X)$ and all $n \geq 0$.
Applying this to $X = U \cap V \cong * \sqcup *$ then explains the passage you quote.

Thanks !! Is there any analogy for the induced maps on $H_1(-)$ or higher?

The statement about disjoint unions holds in all degrees, but $f_*\colon H_n(X) \to H_n(Y)$ is generally non-trivial (and often difficult to determine). The only thing you can really say in general is that there are natural isomorphisms $H_n(X) \cong \pi_n(X)^{\mathrm{ab}}$ where the right hand side is the abelianization of the $n$th homotopy group of $X$, provided that $X$ is path-connected, but only in the lowest interesting degree, i.e. it holds only if $H_m(X) = 0$ for all $0 < m < n$ (this is the content of the Hurewicz theorem).

The "natural" here in particular means that under this isomorphism the two maps $f_\colon H_n(X) \to H_n(Y)$ and $f_\colon \pi_n(X)^{\mathrm{ab}} \to \pi_n(Y)^{\mathrm{ab}}$ are the same (also note that $\pi_k(X)$ is already abelian if $k > 1$, so the ${{-}}^{\mathrm{ab}}$ is only necessary for the $k = 1$ case). But induced maps on homotopy groups are generally not easier to understand than those on homology, and this is pretty much all you can say in general.
